# QTableView in MainWindow and tab ordering

Tags: c++, qt

I Have a problem. When place (for example) two or more `QTableView`s into `MainWindow`, no work tab ordering.
Why?  Because tab is capture by `QTableView` (pointer to the cell `QTableView`). How can I send TAB into `QMainWindow`? I can change focus form one `QTableView` to another one when tab was pressed.

How can I do it? Can anyone help me please?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFileSystemModel *myModel;
    myModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    myModel->setReadOnly(true);
    myModel->setRootPath("C:\\");
    ui->tableView->setModel(myModel);
    ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui->tableView->setRootIndex(myModel->index("C:\\"));


    QFileSystemModel *myModel2;
    myModel2 = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    myModel2->setReadOnly(true);
    myModel2->setRootPath("C:\\");
    ui->tableView_2->setModel(myModel2);
    ui->tableView_2->setRootIndex(myModel2->index("C:\\"));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Are you asking that the `Tab` key doesn't work as you expect, when you have two `QTableView`s inside one `QMainWindow`? What is the behaviour you expect, and what is the behaviour you get instead? Also, please provide some code on how do you created the `QTableView`s and inserted them inside the `QMainWindow`.

Comment: In code is nothing special. My problem is, that qtableview swallows TAB due to move the pointer to the cell. I place it here. One moment. But when you try it, you must have a same problem. Place Two QTableView(with any items and any collumns) in to MainWindow and then pres tab for change focus to second qtableview. You fail in this moment. Because tab will be catch and stay in QTableView (not emited to mainwindow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have two `QTableView`s inside a single `QMainWindow` (for instance, using a `QGridLayout`) and possibly other `QWidget`s, and you want to navigate the *keyboard focus* between them, but you can't because the keyboard focus stays on a `QTableView` (most likely the first one).

If this is the case, you should try these options (possibly together):

First, reimplements the keyPressEvent of your `QTableView` like this:

```
void MyTableView::keyPressEvent (QKeyEvent * event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
        event->ignore();
    else
        QTableView::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Secondly, in the constructor of you table view, disabling keyboard focus (so that the focus will cycle through your other widgets only by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

```
void MyTableView::MyTableView()
{
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus); // allow giving focus with mouse click,
                                    // but not with TAB key
}
```

Finally in the constructor of your `QMainWindow`, after creating and adding the table views in the layout, you can give your main window the focus (that has be taken by the table views, unless you did the second point), by calling:

```
void MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow()
{
    setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
}
```

**Update**

The following complete minimal example compiles and works as expected for me: I have two `TableView`s next to each other on top, and two buttons on bottom. Using <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between these 4 widgets, without modifying whose cells are selected/highlighted in the `TableView`s. I can get the focus on a desired `TableView` either by selecting them with the mouse, or by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Once the focus is on the the desired `TableView`, I can move through the cells using the keyboard arrows (or clicking with the mouse).

```
#include <QtGui>

class TableView: public QTableView
{
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
    {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
            event->ignore();
        else
            QTableView::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout();

    // the first Model/View pair
    QFileSystemModel * model1 = new QFileSystemModel();
    model1->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    TableView * view1 = new TableView();
    view1->setModel(model1);
    layout->addWidget(view1,0,0);

    // the second Model/View pair
    QFileSystemModel * model2 = new QFileSystemModel();
    model2->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    TableView * view2 = new TableView();
    view2->setModel(model2);
    layout->addWidget(view2,0,1);

    // Other widgets
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Hello"),1,0);
    layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("World"),1,1);

    // Create the window containing them and show it
    QWidget * w = new QWidget();
    w->setLayout(layout);
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: It's what I mean, thank you very much (event->igonre()). Now I have a litle problem :-). When first QTableVeiw lost focus, I can't return it back by mouse. That's a different type of event isn't it?

Comment: @exo normally, if you use `setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);`, it should work, while `setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);` also forbid getting focus by mouse click. You've probably seen my answer before I edited it ;-)

Comment: @exo in doubt, you can also leave it at `Qt::StrongFocus` (that I believe is the default for `QTableView`), so you can *also* go into the table by using TAB.

Comment: Sorry, it was my problem. Now all is ok.

Comment: @exo Perfect, glad it helped :-) So you should mark my answer as "accepted", see the [about page of StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to learn in 1min how the site works :-)

Comment: I havel small reputation :-( to doing it. Maybe it will be possible later. If my reputation rises. I'm sure I'll still have some questions.

Comment: @exo Try harder ;-) What you can't do is "upvoting the question" (clicking on the up arrow), but you still can "mark it as accepted" (clicking on the accepting mark, just below the down arrow)

Comment: Hi, the program still does not work properly. `event->ignore();` is fine, but the tab is still not working as I need.
`setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);` in QTableVeiw can not be used because then the focus can not be controlled with the mouse.
If I only use `event->ignore();` cursor changing focus from one to the other QTableView, but at the same time moves 
from cell to cell. When the focus turns enough times (equals the number of cells per row), it goes to the next line, 
and it's a problem :-(.

Comment: @exo See my edit, everything works fine for me. Compile and test the minimal example I've given to you, and tell me if it works as you expect. If not, explain precisely with details (similar to what is described in my answer): 1) what is the behaviour you get. 2) What is the behaviour you want.

Comment: I don't understand it. I have the same example as you, but I have special class for QTableView. Your example works perfect. My still not work. I'm going to find where exactly the problem is.

Comment: @exo: this is why it is so important to always create this MCE (Minimal Compilable Example). It helps you (and often, me ;-) ) to know if the issue is about the code you are adding/testing, or actually lies hidden elsewhere. :-) Now that you are sure how it is supposed to work, and that it does work in normal circonstances, you can either add lines to this MCE until it breaks, or remove lines from your actual code until it's fixed, so you know which specific lines breaks it :-)

Comment: The error was, that I used `eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)` instead of `keyPeressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)`
Now works perfect. Thank you.
Now i have last problem with this. I need to capture ctrl+tab.
But this pice of code does not work
`if(event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier && event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
event->ignore();` What is wrong there?

Comment: You probably want this: `if(!(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) && event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) event->ignore();` :-) This will also capture things like Shift+Control TAB. If you only want to capture Control TAB (no other modifiers, then `if(!(event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier) && event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) event->ignore();`

Comment: Of course... error is on my side. I thought Shift+TAB. Problem is only when use Shift modifier. In ctrl+tab example everything is ok.

Comment: Uáááá I find it. it's `if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab)`